# Adding coordinates to map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, coordinates, excel

I am trying to make a map using ArcMap 10.3 and adding Excel coordinates from a map. I originally converted addresses to lat/long using an online site. I have tried every suggestion I could find online and I can't figure how to get the points to show up. I've been able to upload the Excel file and add xy coordinates, but nothing shows up when I do. I only have 12 addresses/coordinate pair to add so I also tried to add them individually and couldn't figure out how. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include a sample point or two within the question. i don't know if this was occurring in 10.3, but make sure the Add XY tool's coordinate system is correct. If the data's lat/lon, make sure coordsys is a geographic one.

Answer (score 1):

1) Save the excel doc as a .xls file.
2) Open ArcMap
3) Set the coordinate system to WGS84 if you have basic lat/long coordinates.
4) Add data (the xls doc)
5) Right click the table in the ToC and run the XY to point tool.
6) I recommend exporting the point file to a new layer.

Comment: I'd suggest not using Excel directly, it has weak types which can cause problems later. Save the Excel sheet as DBASE IV or import into a personal geodatabase using MS Access before adding the table to the TOC and creating event layer http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-xy-event-layer.htm are the coords in DD lat/lon or DMS lat/lon? If you have DMS it will need to be converted to DD for the XY event layer to work, that can be done in Excel before saving.